# Enable content security warning message is not displaying for a specific excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I am working one excel template which has Macro code. While opening this file , in my machine ,enable content security warning is not appearing and macros are automatically enabling. This is happening to only this file.
For other excel templates with Macro code , iam getting the security alert. We reinstalled Microsoft Office and  version iam using is Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20164) 64-bit.

Reinstalled MS Office , cleared Trusted Documents, Cleared TEMP Files

Comment: Is the template stored in a trusted location? The default template folder of Excel is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Templates\` and that is, as far as I know, set as trusted location per default.